# Disparate forms in single Django formset

Tags: django-forms

In my model, I have a class *Condition* and two subclasses, *StringCondition* and *NumCondition*.  The user will view/edit/order conditions as a single list.

Is there any way to implement this with a Django modelform formset?  I'm currently using two separate formsets (one for NumConditions, one for StringConditions), but it's a pain to manually interweave the ordering (so a number condition can appear between two string conditions, etc).

Answer (score 2):

Beginning in Django 1.3, you can override the `__iter__()` method of a formset to control the order that the forms are rendered. To utilize this feature you'll need to do two things: first tag your forms so you can order them, and second render the formset as `for form in formset` (instead of the old `for form in formset.forms`). Then create an `__iter__()` method to order the forms & you're in business.

Kent

Comment: Don't forget the [indexing override](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#formsets) if you do that. (From the linked docs --> Formsets can also be indexed into, which returns the corresponding form. If you override __iter__, you will need to also override __getitem__ to have matching behavior.)